# How settings.hex is created in linux

Tags: linux, settings, movesense

Creation of settings.hex file for bootloader has a wrong address. I believe the correct address is 0x7F000 but it is 0xFF000 which is illegal address. This can be edited manually but it's frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should create an issue if it is a bug.

The bugtracker of the movesense software:
https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/issues?status=new&status=open